# Project local keyword highlighting

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I want to enable syntax highlighting for custom types in C files. So, in order to highlight a type name `MyCoolType`, I add the following line to ~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim:

```
syn keyword Type MyCoolType
```

This works as I expect it. The keyword is highlighted with the color of the Type group.

Now I want to highlight custom types on a per project basis. To do so, I can manually issue `:syn keyword Type MyCoolType`, which also highlights the keyword in a currently loaded buffer. This is, however, tedious.

When I add the command to my project-local .vimrc, highlighting does not work. I also tried the following autocommands in my project-local .vimrc, which both did not work.

```
au BufRead *.c syn keyword Type MyCoolType
au FileType c syn keyword Type MyCoolType
```

Where and how do I define project local keyword highlighting in Vim 8.2?

Comment: Using `au FileType c` works for me, but maybe you have a different C syntax file? Try using `au Syntax c` so it gets triggered after the `syntax` option is set (which happens after `filetype`).

Comment: Is the first line of code supposed to be `syn[tax] keyword …`?

Comment: There was some strange interference with [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot). The autocommand started working as soon as vim-polyglot was deactivated. After de- and reinstall, the autocommand works now with vim-polyglot activated. I have no clue about the root of the problem.